# when is okay to close my post

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have a few posts which have no answers, and I have either moved on or applied a ridiculous workaround that I want to forget it. Should I close these?

For example:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15471/deleting-a-timer-job-via-stsadm-in-moss2007

[Completely empty content database](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14225/completely-empty-content-database)

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/infopath-form-erroring-dtd-is-prohibited

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution to those posts is to post your workaround. I've done it before...If you don't have an answer by now, there may not be a better answer than your workaround.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the three up there, I remember one work around, one we never resolved and moved on, and the other i completely forget

Comment: +1 because more information is better. Also, remember that "not possible" is also a valid answer. If you feel like your question could help someone else.. leave it open.

Comment: I've closed a question before because after I asked it, I realized that the premise on which I based it was flawed - in other words, I realized I was an idiot for asking it and that it was rather a stupid question in the first place, even though it had perpelexed me enough to ask...